# How to wait on a scala Future in java code

Tags: java, scala, akka, scala-java-interop

I am trying to do akka coding in java and I have a need to do a blocking call. I understand that Await.result can be used to block which is great but I can't figure out how to get an Awaitable which is what the Await.result call requires.

Here is my code where I am able to get to a scala Future. I need help getting an awaitable from the future.

```
    final Timeout t = new Timeout(Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

    final ArrayList<Future<Object>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Object>>();

    futures.add(ask(foo, "message", 5000));

    final Future<Iterable<Object>> aggregate = Futures.sequence(futures,
        this.actorSystem.dispatcher());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[the docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future) say:

```
trait Future[+T] extends Awaitable[T]
```

The future *is* an awaitable.